# Converting a list into Json object Error Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, data-structures

List Element results[0]:

```
{"uuid": "4bhbhj-483-hbej-7848", "sequence_id": 6428749884, "is_recovery": null, "parent_uuid": null, "branding": "somerandom", "channel": "fcs", "ext_interaction_id": "8476565", "external_url": "hngjrnhhng", "language": "en", "survey_id": 53443, "survey_name": "somerandom", "tags": ["somerandom", "ceh-yr", "email", "somerandom", "somerandom", "ebfbvf", "jnfk"], "request_created_at": "2021-07-13T23:41:33.358Z", "request_delivery_status": "Not sent: suppression period", "request_sent_at": "2021-07-13T23:41:33.358Z", "requested_via": "API", "delivered_at": null, "response_received_at": null, "reward_eligible": null, "reward_name": null, "marketing": {"custom_link_eligible": False, "custom_link_initiated": False, "facebook_follow_eligible": False, "facebook_follow_initiated": False, "facebook_share_eligible": False, "facebook_share_initiated": False, "twitter_follow_eligible": False, "twitter_follow_initiated": False, "twitter_share_eligible": False, "twitter_share_initiated": False}, "employee": {"custom_id": null, "email": "somerandom@hfkjd.com", "first_name": "some", "last_name": "random"}, "team_leader": {"custom_id": null, "full_name": "random, some"}, "customer": {"custom_id": null, "email": "bchjdhbgf@somemail.com", "full_name": "Jane Doe"}, "custom_properties": null, "answers": null}
```

The reason I am trying to pass this as a Json object is so that it's easily parsable in Snowflake. I am using DataFrames. I want to pass this list as a json object but it converts the list into string. See code below:

```
results=process()
finaldata=json.dumps(results)
print(type(results)) # returns <class 'list'>
print(type(finaldata)) # returns <class 'str'>
# print (finaldata)
df=pd.DataFrame(finaldata,columns =["Data"])
```

Error while trying to execute the above code:

```
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 529, in __init__
raise ValueError("DataFrame constructor not properly called!")
```

ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

What am I doing wrong that the list is getting converted into a str and not json object?

Comment: There are no `json` objects in python. There are `list`s, `dict`s and `str`s amongst many types but only some `str`s are considered valid `json`. The `json` lib works by, for example, converting a `list` to a `str`. This is what you have successfully done.

Answer (score 1):

so when you dumping this list of dicts you are making string. You can't build dataframe from string. You can just pass your list to dataframe. If you want to use your dumped string to build dataframe you have to use **json.load()**, which builda again list of dicts. So basicialy you will get to the starting point :)
following code should be fine:

```
result = {"uuid": "4bhbhj-483-hbej-7848", "sequence_id": 6428749884, "is_recovery": None, "parent_uuid": None, "branding": "somerandom", "channel": "fcs", "ext_interaction_id": "8476565", "external_url": "hngjrnhhng", "language": "en", "survey_id": 53443, "survey_name": "somerandom", "tags": ["somerandom", "ceh-yr", "email", "somerandom", "somerandom", "ebfbvf", "jnfk"], "request_created_at": "2021-07-13T23:41:33.358Z", "request_delivery_status": "Not sent: suppression period", "request_sent_at": "2021-07-13T23:41:33.358Z", "requested_via": "API", "delivered_at": None, "response_received_at": None, "reward_eligible": None, "reward_name": None, "marketing": {"custom_link_eligible": False, "custom_link_initiated": False, "facebook_follow_eligible": False, "facebook_follow_initiated": False, "facebook_share_eligible": False, "facebook_share_initiated": False, "twitter_follow_eligible": False, "twitter_follow_initiated": False, "twitter_share_eligible": False, "twitter_share_initiated": False}, "employee": {"custom_id": None, "email": "somerandom@hfkjd.com", "first_name": "some", "last_name": "random"}, "team_leader": {"custom_id": None, "full_name": "random, some"}, "customer": {"custom_id": None, "email": "bchjdhbgf@somemail.com", "full_name": "Jane Doe"}, "custom_properties": None, "answers": None}
list_of_results = [result,result,result] # just example    
string_json_to_load = json.dumps(list_of_results )
df = pd.DataFrame(list)
df.head()
```

| index | uuid | sequence_id | is_recovery | parent_uuid | branding | channel |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4bhbhj-483-hbej-7848 | None | None | None | somerandom | fcs |
| 1 | 4bhbhj-483-hbej-7848 | None | None | None | somerandom | fcs |
| 2 | 4bhbhj-483-hbej-7848 | None | None | None | somerandom | fcs |

3 rows × 26 columns
If you only want to pass this one element of list to dataframe this should works too:

```
final_data = json.dumps(result)
df = pd.read_json(final_data,orient='index').transpose()
df.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

- `json.dumps()` encodes a **dict/list** into a string representation of JSON
- hence `print(type(finaldata)) # returns <class 'str'>` is expected as it is the results of `json.dumps()`
- `pd.DataFrame()` takes predefined **list/dict** structures and builds a data frame.  There is no constructor that takes a string encoding of JSON.  Hence the error you are getting is fully expected
- it's not clear what you are actually looking to achieve.  Below code shows how you can construct a valid `pd.DataFrame()` format **dict/list** to build a dataframe from your sample **dict** into a single row / column dataframe

```
null = None
results = {"uuid": "4bhbhj-483-hbej-7848", "sequence_id": 6428749884, "is_recovery": null, "parent_uuid": null, "branding": "somerandom", "channel": "fcs", "ext_interaction_id": "8476565", "external_url": "hngjrnhhng", "language": "en", "survey_id": 53443, "survey_name": "somerandom", "tags": ["somerandom", "ceh-yr", "email", "somerandom", "somerandom", "ebfbvf", "jnfk"], "request_created_at": "2021-07-13T23:41:33.358Z", "request_delivery_status": "Not sent: suppression period", "request_sent_at": "2021-07-13T23:41:33.358Z", "requested_via": "API", "delivered_at": null, "response_received_at": null, "reward_eligible": null, "reward_name": null, "marketing": {"custom_link_eligible": False, "custom_link_initiated": False, "facebook_follow_eligible": False, "facebook_follow_initiated": False, "facebook_share_eligible": False, "facebook_share_initiated": False, "twitter_follow_eligible": False, "twitter_follow_initiated": False, "twitter_share_eligible": False, "twitter_share_initiated": False}, "employee": {"custom_id": null, "email": "somerandom@hfkjd.com", "first_name": "some", "last_name": "random"}, "team_leader": {"custom_id": null, "full_name": "random, some"}, "customer": {"custom_id": null, "email": "bchjdhbgf@somemail.com", "full_name": "Jane Doe"}, "custom_properties": null, "answers": null}
pd.DataFrame({"data":{0:results}})
```